# A simple question regarding "require", in smart contracts

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I was going through an open source github repo of a deed smart contract.
And I have a question about a specific line of code. I just want to know what does
`require(block.timestamp >= earliest,"too early")`mean?This is the smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Deed {
  address public lawyer;
  address payable public beneficiary;
  uint public earliest;

  constructor(
    address _lawyer, 
    address payable _beneficiary, 
    uint fromNow) 
    payable {
    lawyer = _lawyer;
    beneficiary = _beneficiary; 
    earliest = block.timestamp + fromNow;
  }

  function withdraw() public {
    require(msg.sender == lawyer, 'lawyer only');
    require(block.timestamp >= earliest, 'too early');
    beneficiary.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'require' can be used to check for conditions and throw an exception if the condition is not met.

'block.timestamp' is a Unix time stamp. So, it has the complete information about the date, hours, minutes, and seconds (in UTC) when the block was created.

> earliest = block.timestamp + fromNow

'earliest' is initialised when the constructor is run ie. the contract is deployed, to the value  contract_deployment_epoch_block_time + 'fromNow'

> require(block.timestamp >= earliest, 'too early');

On running the function withdraw(), this require statement checks if enough(fromNow epoch) time has passed and fails if its too early

Answer (score 1):

The function will revert any state changes that were created during execution if a require statement fails.

`block.timestamp` is the time of the block generation in seconds.
If not enough time is passed from the lower bound (`earliest`) the function will revert.

See documentations of [require](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=timestamp#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require) and [block timestamp](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties)